# How can i calculate the minimum by month of a data frame of an expanding window?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

i have a data frame that looks like this :

| date | y |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-12-01 | 1 |
| 2021-12-02 | 2 |
| 2021-12-03 | 3 |
| 2021-12-04 | 4 |
| 2021-12-05 | 5 |
| 2021-12-06 | 6 |
| 2022-01-01 | 10 |
| 2022-01-02 | 20 |
| 2022-01-03 | 30 |
| 2022-01-04 | 40 |
| 2022-01-05 | 50 |
| 2022-01-06 | 60 |
| 2022-02-01 | 0.1 |
| 2022-02-02 | 0.2 |
| 2022-02-03 | 0.3 |
| 2022-02-04 | 0.4 |
| 2022-02-05 | 0.5 |
| 2022-02-06 | 0.6 |
| 2022-03-01 | 0.01 |
| 2022-03-02 | 0.02 |
| 2022-03-03 | 0.03 |
| 2022-03-04 | 0.04 |
| 2022-03-05 | 0.05 |
| 2022-03-06 | 0.06 |

i want to group them by month but i want to calculate the minimum of each month but as month forwards to contain the information from all the previous history . Like an expanding by month.
For example the minimum of month 12 of year 2021 is 1 and has 6 obs.The next month 1 of year 2022 has minimum 1 because contains the information from december 2021 and has 12 obs.And so on and so forth .

Ideally i want the resulted data frame to be like this :

| year | month | obs | minimum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 12 | 6 | 1 |
| 2022 | 1 | 12 | 1 |
| 2022 | 2 | 18 | 0.1 |
| 2022 | 3 | 24 | 0.01 |

How can i do this in R ?

```
date = c(seq(as.Date("2021/12/1"), by = "day", length.out = 6),
         seq(as.Date("2022/1/1"), by = "day", length.out = 6),
         seq(as.Date("2022/2/1"), by = "day", length.out = 6),
         seq(as.Date("2022/3/1"), by = "day", length.out = 6))
y = c(seq(1:6),seq(10,60,by=10),seq(0.1,0.6,by=0.1),seq(0.01,0.06,by=0.01))
df = tibble(date,y);df
```

Comment: Group by just month or year/month?

Comment: @Sotos this is the first step and it is easy.The next step is expand it by month

Comment: @Sotos this will calculate just the minimum of each month.Not in an expanding framework

Comment: Yes I got it. The way I 'd approach it is via `Reduce(..., accumulate = TRUE)`. No time to do it now but I hope this gets you in a direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this achieve what you're looking for?

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df |> 
  mutate(year = year(date), month = month(date)) |> 
  group_by(year, month) |> 
  summarise(obs = n(), minimum = min(y),
            .groups = "drop") |> 
  mutate(obs = cumsum(obs),
         minimum = cummin(minimum))
#> # A tibble: 4 × 4
#>    year month   obs minimum
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <int>   <dbl>
#> 1  2021    12     6    1   
#> 2  2022     1    12    1   
#> 3  2022     2    18    0.1 
#> 4  2022     3    24    0.01
```

Comment: good approach.Thank you very much for your effort and time spend on it.I appreciate it